# Looping through subindex jquery each

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to loop through some JSON code but it's a bit more complicated than a simple `$.each(data, function(key, value){};`
as you can see, the JSON is wrapped once again. when i just use `$.each(data, function(key, value){};`i get: `data : [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`. How can i get the data inside the subobjects?

Thanks!

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "title": "nummer 6",
      "application": "afbeeldingVerhalen",
      "language": "de_DE",
      "id": "",
      "image": ""
    },
    {
      "objAudio": "",
      "objImage": "",
      "objText": "",
      "objLocation": {
        "X": "70.99527740478516",
        "Y": "166.853759765625"
      }
    },
    {
      "objAudio": "",
      "objImage": "",
      "objText": "",
      "objLocation": {
        "X": "70.99527740478516",
        "Y": "166.853759765625"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

## Edit

Thanks for the link i found out how to fix it:

```
$.each(data['data'], function(key, value){
        $.each(data['data'][key], function(key, value){
            console.log(value);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Which properties do you need to get? The objects in the array are in different formats which complicates things

Comment: Go through duplicate link. If that doesn't help then post actual code used...not snippets that don't reveal anything